# Is the Perl 6 documentation available for e-readers?

Tags: raku

I wonder, whether [the Perl 6 documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/) is available in some format for e-readers (epub / mobi / fb2). I tried to make an epub out of [this web-page](https://docs.perl6.org/perl6.xhtml), where all the docs are conveniently combined into one file. Unfortunately, the wonderful 4-level structure is ignored by available converters, so I get a huge epub without bookmarks, which it's impossible to navigate.

So, does anyone know where to find, or can make themselves an epub/mobi out of the [Perl 6 docs](https://docs.perl6.org/perl6.xhtml) with bookmarks?

Quick googling leads me to [python docs' epub](https://docs.python.org/3/download.html). :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go: https://temp.perl6.party/pub/2017/PSix-Docs-Oct-30-2017.epub

I've used [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/download) with the [single-page docs](https://docs.perl6.org/perl6.xhtml) you mentioned and in "Convert individually"->"Table of Contents" told it to use `h1`, `h2`, and `h3` selectors to figure out where the level 1, 2, and 3 heading are at. Other than [some rendering bugs](https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/1285), seems to work.

---

In 2018, I'm hoping we'll make a `Pod::To::SQL` that'll load up our docs into an SQLite database, with each bit of info tagged appropriately. This will let us make a better dynamic site, make `p6doc` tool more useful, and cater to more usecases like yours: creating standalone version of (subset of) docs in various formats.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's marvelous! At some point my Calibre refused to convert TOC from my files, though I tell him about the `h1` and other levels. :(

Comment: I just loaded that into my FBReader library and viewed it on my Nexus 7 Android tablet. There are some problems; part of the table of contents are out of order, and the initial "Welcome" page is squeezed into about the right 15% of the screen. It looks OK in Calibre on Ubuntu.

Comment: @KeithThompson no idea how to go about fixing that. Sorry.